# I'm trying to get an element by it index of a slice in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, go

What I need is just the lobby map, instead of it returning a map with the lobby map inside prefix with `firstLobby:`

```
func GetLobbyByIndex(id string) error {
    _id, err := ConvertStringToOBjectID(id)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    filter := bson.M{"_id": _id}
    projection := bson.M{"firstLobby": bson.M{
        "$arrayElemAt": []interface{}{"$day1.lobbies", 0},
    }}

    var ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    cursor, err := AttendanceCollection.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{
        {{"$match", filter}},
        {{"$project", projection}},
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var result = bson.M{}
        cursor.Decode(&result)
        fmt.Println(result)

    }
    return nil
}
```

I will appreciate if I can get a way to solve this, if you need me to drop codes, like the lobby model, let me know.

Comment: can you add your epected result

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the key from 'firstLobby' to 'lobby' so that lobby map can be accessed :

```
func GetLobbyByIndex(id string) error {
    _id, err := ConvertStringToOBjectID(id)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    filter := bson.M{"_id": _id}
    projection := bson.M{"lobby": bson.M{
        "$arrayElemAt": []interface{}{"$day1.lobbies", 0},
    }}

    var ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    cursor, err := AttendanceCollection.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{
        {{"$match", filter}},
        {{"$project", projection}},
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var result = bson.M{}
        cursor.Decode(&result)
        fmt.Println(result)

    }
    return nil
}
```